# I'm trying to query a database to give me only subscribed users

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-asyncio, fastapi

So i have a database that i am trying to query to give me just users email from the users models but i only want the emails if that user has a subscription from the subscription models or has been validated as been present in that model

```py
#the models

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column("user_id", String(64), primary_key=True, index=True, default=str(uuid4()))
    email = Column(String(30))
    name = Column(String(30))
    password = Column(String(100))

    customer = relationship("Customer", back_populates="user_value")
    subscription_value = relationship("Subscription", back_populates="user_sub")

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customer"

    user_id = Column(String(64), ForeignKey("user.user_id"))
    customer_id = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, index=True, default=str(uuid4))
    session_id = Column(String(64))

    subscription_value = relationship("Subscription", back_populates="customer_value")


class Subscription(Base):
    __tablename__ = "subscription"

    user_id = Column(String(64), ForeignKey("user.user_id"))
    subscription_id = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, index=True, default=str(uuid4))

    customer_value = relationship("Customer", back_populates="subscription_value")
    product_value = relationship("Product", back_populates="sub_value")
```

This is the code I have tried

```py
async def send_user_email(company_ranks):
    db: Session = next(get_db())

    # get users emails
    emails = db.query(models.User.email).all()
    users = db.query(models.Subscription).filter(models.Subscription.user_id == id)

    if users.subscription_id in models.Subscription:
        emails = db.query(models.User.email).all()

    await send_mail(subject, emails, body)
```

This is what my get_db() looks like:

```
def get_db():
    """Gets the database from the local session"""
    db = database.SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? Some error in the code? Error in the SQL? Just wrong output?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and give more details, like what is company ranks?, can you show us the code of get_db()?

Comment: @takendarkk there's no output when i try to print emails after the if statement in the function

Comment: @OrfeasBourchas i added what get_db looks like to the edit and company ranks is a json data. Apologies if i'm making this more complicated

Comment: I don't see `id` defined anywhere.  Unless you override it, `id` is the name of a built-in Python function, which is never going to be found in your database.

Comment: What is database that has as method the SessionLocal?

Comment: i am using sqlalchemy and following the tutorial sessionlocal looks like this:
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Comment: You can use a plain join to only get the users that have a reference in the Subscription model; something like `db.query(models.User.email).join(models.Subscription).all()`. If you need to give the join condition, `join(models.Subscription, models.Subscription.user_id == models.User.id)`